# Executing C# code on first page load

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a public static method `string SomeMethod(string message)` inside a `SomeClass` class which gets a string as input and returns something like

```
<div>message</div>
```

Of course this is over-simplificated, but the idea is just like this. Now I would like to do something like

```
<script language="javascript">var string = <% $SomeClass.SomeMethod('asdada');></script>
```

the first time the page is loaded, but I don't really know how can I do it. That just gives me an "object expected" error in JavaScript. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: did you try $(Document).ready( function { var string = $someclass.somemethod(); });

Comment: Seperation of concerns state this is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your server side tags to output something, you should use:

```
 <%: yourCode %>
```

Your code, invokes the method, but does not send the output to the page:

```
 <script>var string=<% yourMethodCall() %></script>
 /* Result = */
 <script>var string=</script>
 /* ASP.Net code is translated to this serverside code: */
 Response.Write("<script>var string=");
 yourMethodCall();
 Response.Write("</script>");

 <script>var string=<%: yourMethodCall() %></script>
 /*                   ^ */
 /* Result = */
 <script>var string=outputOfYourMethod</script>
 /* ASP.Net code is translated to this serverside code */
 Response.Write("<script>var string=");
 Response.Write(HtmlEncode(yourMethodCall()));
 Response.Write("</script>");
```

And, if this is a serverside class, why do you include the `$` sign?

Answer (score 1):

You may put the method to create/register client script dynamically in Page_Load, and check if the page is a postback or not in the Page_Load, and if it's not, run the register script code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap this with quotes and replace the double quotes with the proper escape sequence as well:

```
var string = "<%=SomeClass.SomeMethod("asdada").Replace("\"", "\\\"")%>";
```